# Show that $\sum_{i=0}^{2k} [ {n\choose i+1} + (-1)^{i+1}{n+i+1\choose i+1} ] \sum_{j=0}^i {i\choose j}(-1)^j (i+1-j)^{2k} =0.$

Tags: co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, stirling-numbers

Let $u(k,j) = 1$ if $j=0$, $0$ if $j > k$, or else it is $j*u(k-1,j-1) +(j+1)*u(k-1,j) $. Prove that $ \sum_{i=0}^{2k} {n \choose i+1} u(2k,i) +\sum_{i=0}^{2k} {-n-1 \choose i+1} u(2k,i)=0.   $ This problem is provable using Bernoulli numbers but I'm interested if there's a proof that doesn't require the Bernoulli numbers. Any thoughts or ideas?

By the way it follows that $u(k,j) = \sum_{i=0}^j {j\choose i}(-1)^i (j+1-i)^k$.

Comment: $u(k,j)$ can be expressed in terms of Stirling numbers of the second kind by $u(k,j) = j!\,S(k+1,j+1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by Ira Gessel, $u(k,j)=j!S(k+1,j+1)$. Correspondingly, the sum in question reduces to
$$f_{2k}(n) + f_{2k}(-n-1),$$
where
$$f_k(t):=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} S(k+1,i)\frac{(t)_i}i,$$
where $(t)_i := t(t-1)\cdots(t-i+1)$ is the falling factorial.

Using the recurrence $S(k+1,i)=iS(k,i)+S(k,i-1)$, we get
$$f_k(t)=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} S(k,i)(t)_i + \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} S(k,i-1)\frac{(t)_i}{i} =t^{k} + \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} S(k,i-1)\frac{(t)_i}{i}.$$
Now, for a positive integer $t$, we have $\frac{(t)_i}{i} = \sum_{j=0}^{t-1} (j)_{i-1}$, and thus
$$f_k(t) = t^{k} + \sum_{j=0}^{t-1} j^{k} = \sum_{j=0}^t j^{k}.$$
Similarly, for a negative integer $t$, we get $f_k(t) = (-1)^{k+1}\sum_{j=0}^{-t-1} j^{k}$.

From the obtained formulae for $f_k$ it follows that
$$f_{2k}(n) + f_{2k}(-n-1) = 0.$$

Comment: Falling factorial: $(t)_i = t(t-1)(t-2)\cdots (t-i+1)$.

Comment: Is there any way you might be able to go over the last part again, slowly? I get all of it right until the last part, how does it follow?

Comment: @BenjaminWarren: We have $f_{2k}(n)=\sum_{j=0}^n j^{2k}$ and $f_{2k}(-n-1)=-\sum_{j=0}^n j^{2k}$, and so $f_{2k}(n)+f_{2k}(-n-1)=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your working on this.

Comment: Also, how'd you get the formula $f_k (t)$ for negative $t$? Is there a derivation or name for it?

Comment: @BenjaminWarren: For a negative integer $t$, we have a formula $$\frac{(t)_i}{i} = - \sum_{j=0}^{-t} (-j)_{i-1},$$ which is plugged in and used similarly.

Comment: @BenjaminWarren: Actually, the formula $\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} S(k,i-1) \frac{(t)_i}i = \sum_{j=0}^{t-1} j^k$ appears in *[Concrete Mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_Mathematics)* on p. 275.